# Pylance Showing Yellow Wavy Line Under Module Name When Importing It Even Code Works Fine

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

[image]

Pylance is showing reportMissingImports even I installed it and code works fine.
I can run the code but it was still a very annoying nuisance.
How do I fix this?
I tried restarting Visual Studio Code and look at it again.
Didn't work.

Here is my code.
Perhaps it will help.

```py
import cryptocode

str_encoded = cryptocode.encrypt("Encrypted Text", "p")
## And then to decode it:
str_decoded = cryptocode.decrypt(str_encoded, "p")
print(str_decoded)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure you have selected the correct python interpreter.**

In your picture it is clear that you have chosen `python310` version interpreter, but your cryptocode package is installed under `python311` version.

[image]

**How to choose a python interpreter:**

Click directly on the python version in the lower right corner or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette and choose **Python:Select Interpreter**, then choose the appropriate python interpreter.

**Why did you choose the wrong interpreter and still run successfully:**

You run the code directly using the `python` command in the terminal, your computer should have the environment variable `python311` added, or other settings make it the default python version is `311`.

If you run the code with the play button in the top right corner, it will use the python interpreter you chose for VS Code (in this case you will get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptocode'` error).